# meaning of the phrase "be huge to" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/Objoad6rG6U). It is right at the beginning.

> Today we are going to talk about a topic so **huge** to history buffs, that we can only discuss it a tiny, little fraction of it.

Does he mean the topic is very loved by the buffs or that it is literary very big to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence means that there is a lot to know or to say about the topic. For example, it might be very complex or multifaceted, such one would have to understand many different details in order to grasp the entire concept. The meaning is indicated by the clause that follows, "that we can only discuss a tiny, little fraction of it." (I have removed the first occurrence of the word "it", which was not grammatical.) In other words, there is much to learn about the topic, and the information that follows in the course is only a small sample.